# How to make this bowl smooth from flat sides

Tags: modeling

[image: Bowl]

I just want it to look clean and smooth.

remark: I have a engraving on the bottom so just shade smooth won't work.

Comment: right mouse and select Shade Smooth

Answer (score 0):

RIGHT CLICK ON OBJECT AND CLICK "SMOOTH SHADE"[image]

Comment: I have a engraving on the bottom and it gets wonky when i do that, not sure how to add photos to this comment lol

Comment: you can add photos in comments by adding a new answer, insert photo there, press on "add image", then copy the link and discard the answer. The just paste the link in the comment

Comment: @xyz programm: consider to not write everything with caps lock because this is often considered as rude.

Comment: okay next time I won't use capslock

Answer (score 0):

use shade smooth but also check this checkbox (autosmooth) here:

[image]

you find it in "object data properties"